# Add CImg library into android NDK (for image processing)

Tags: android, c, image-processing, android-ndk, cimg

How can I add CImg library into android NDK so that I can do Image Processing??
Thanking you in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CImg is a header-only library, so you can just write

```
#include "cimg.h"
```

somewhere in your code. If it fails to compile for Android you will need to fix it yourself or look for other solutions, i.e. [FreeImage.](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net)

Refer to presentation slides for more details: http://cimg.sourceforge.net/CImg_slides.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Create simple example for uses CImg in Android: https://github.com/tttzof351/CImgAndroid